# Is it generally safe to disable Windows 10 Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol (WPAD)?

Tags: wifi, proxy, ip, windows-10

Is it generally safe to disable Windows 10 Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol (WPAD)?

This might be my only option to try before contacting my ISP which could be quite annoying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview of WPAD:**

The Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol (WPAD) is a method used by client devices to locate the URL of a proxy configuration file (e.g. a PAC  file) that is being hosted on the network, using either DHCP and/or DNS discovery methods which differs based upon the browser.

Once a proxy configuration file has been detected and downloaded the browser is configured in an appropriate way to either send web requests via a proxy server, or to bypass the proxy all together and send the web request straight to the web server.

**Answer**

The main point to understand here is why you are looking at disabling WPAD. From a security perspective unless you operate on a network that utilises WPAD and a Web Proxy (unlikely if you're not on an enterprise/business network) there would be no harm in disabling WPAD within each of the browsers that you use.

Based on the questions which you are trying to follow on from I'd take a guess in saying this isn't an area you need to troubleshoot further and the cause of your problem is likely to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

WPAD is a mechanism which helps you to get to the right proxy for your outbound traffic.

If you do not have the right proxy you generally cannot get out. If you can then someone probably made a mistake but it is not your problem.

Not having a WPAD does not present a risk for you as an individual.